# Flash movie behaving really weird, possibly corrupt FLA?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I have an FLA done in Flash 10, and some AS3 code that manipulates a MovieClip in the movie based on the mouseX and mouseY coordinates. Last night the FLA was working 100% perfectly.

This morning things went haywire. Layers on the movie started jerking around severely. So suspecting my formula, I commented it out and replaced it with mx.x = mouseX and likewise for y. Still the mysterious jerking persisted.

My Flash CS4 Pro is updated, and I tried clearing ASO files, Save and Compact, and I checked that I am not having problems with browser cache etc. I restarted Flash, I restarted my machine...I would restart me if I could! :)

I decided to backtrack to an older version I had backed up in a Zip last night, extracted it, published and ran it and it worked perfectly. Then I decided to open the new version again to compare the differences between the two FLA, BUT...for some unexplicable reason, when publishing the broken FLA it just miraculously started working as well!

Bot FLA's have the same formulas for manipulating the sprite, so it's not a code problem.

Does anyone have an idea what possibly went wrong? Did my FLA go corrupt! Am I using some drug in my sleep that causes me to hallucinate?

I am so puzzled about this phenomenon!

Flash behaves weird sometimes, the other day I had MonsterDebugger show up the memory graph (busy scrolling and profiling Flash RAM usage) in its memory monitor, AND I DIDN"T EVEN HAVE A FLASH MOVIE RUNNING!

What on earth is the problem with Flash?

[EDIT]

I've also noticed that Flash player removes a bunch of imports from some of my source files, and then it complains it can't find these things, until I put them back and re-publish.

```
import mx.rpc.http.*;
import mx.rpc.xml.*;
import mx.rpc.events.*;
import fl.data.*;   
import fl.controls.*;
```

When republishing, the SWF works perfectly, until, randomly, it removes them again. It leaves some other imports though? WEIRD!

Comment: I have experienced some weird things with Flash CS4 as well. For example I had a blank .FLA with just a trace statement which worked. But when I then saved the file it would no longer trace or execute any code in it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that could make flash player go crazy. First of all if the debugging player works fine, but the browser player makes crazy things then you probably have to reinstall the flash player. 
if you are on vista systems or other systems with "enhanced" security and/or multiple user accounts, there will be settings to allow (or prevent) access to programs and plug-ins and folders etc.
And there is also the fact that flash player 10 works better in fireFox than in IE.